# How can I retrieve tax details from the Shopify API?

Tags: python, shopify-api

I am currently working on a script to create orders to Shopify. I have not included any tax lines in the JSON, because I want the tax to be automatically calculated using Avalara.

Our Shopify is basically configured to use Avatax to calculate taxes. I am using real addresses using a python library called random-address.

Below is a sample JSON from the script. The shipping address contains real addresses from the random-address python library. Why aren't the tax rates showing automatically in Shopify? Is something being done incorrectly?

```json
line_items = {
            "product_id": 7686908772569,
            "variant_id": 42855453589721,
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 2.00,
            "title": "banana pod 987",
            "taxable": True,
            "order": {
                "customer": {
                    "first_name": data["first_name"],
                    "last_name": data["last_name"],
                },
                "email": data["email"],
                "financial_status": financial_status,
                "line_items": line_items,
                "gateway": "paypal",
                "shipping_address": shipping_address,
                "billing_address": shipping_address,
                "taxes_included" : True,
    
            }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `taxes_included`to `False`.